# SendInput почему гаснет экран

Tags: delphi

После вызова функции SendInput гаснет экран. Почему так происходит? И как можно этого избежать?
 Вот код на делфи после которого гаснет экран:

```
arrI[0].Itype:=INPUT_MOUSE;
arrI[0].mi.dwFlags:=MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE
                           or MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE; 
arrI[0].mi.dx:=w*(65535 div Screen.Width);
arrI[0].mi.dy:=h*(65535 div Screen.Height);

SendInput(1,arrI[0],SizeOf(TInput))
```

Comment: А холодильник тоже выключается ?

Простите, не удержался.

Comment: А не стоит никакой приблуды, которая, если перевести курсор в угол, гасит монитор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, спасибо, сам разобрался, над было массив перед этим обнулить:

```
ZeroMemory(@arrI, SizeOf(TInput) * 1).
```